# Transactions rolling back: user does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add the username of an author to a post in my blog, in order to later be able to verify that the user attempting to alter the post is the original author of the post. However, it is not working, and is returning the error "Validation failed: User must exist", even though the current user does exist, based on the fact that it is displaying the username of the currently logged in user on the page.

Error log:

```
Validation failed: User must exist
@post = Post.new(post_params)
       @post[:author] = current_user.username
->>     if @post.save!
flash[:success] = "Post created."
redirect_to post_path(@post.id)
else
```

Application controller (where current_user is declared):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

helper_method :current_user
helper_method :require_user
def current_user
    return unless session[:user_id]
    current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
end

def require_user 
  redirect_to '/login' unless current_user 
end

end
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.string "author"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Error when I do what Vasilisa said:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (User(#47015106648260) expected, got "test" which is an instance of String(#47015080074780)):

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    ==> @post.author = current_user.username
    if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Post created."
    redirect_to post_path(@post.id)
```

Comment: Add User and Post models to the question, please. And users and posts tables from the `schema.rb` too

Comment: @arehvb please show us more logic. show us your `Post model` your `posts controller` we need to see  `validations` built on the model. We need to see the relations of `Post model` also show us the `schema` of the `Post model`.

Comment: Wild guess: I believe `@post.author = current_user` instead of `@post[:author] = current_user.username` would work.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, it's too easy :)

Comment: @Vasilisa if it was complicated, I would never have showed up in comments :)

Comment: tried doing @post.author, still doesn't work

Comment: @arehvb Please add the files requested by Moustafa. Did you change `current_user.username` to `current_user` when you made the `@post.author` change?

Comment: Why don't you follow Rails conventions and name the column to handle the association to the user `user_id`?

Answer (score 1):

The Post model `belongs_to :user`, in ROR 5 this association validates for presence automatically. That's why you're getting "Validation failed: User must exist". Looks like you want to store post's user as `author` in db.

Change your posts table in migration

```
def change
  remove_column :posts, :author, :string
  add_reference :posts, :author
end
```

In the Post model change `belongs_to :user` to `belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'`

Add to the User model

```
has_many :posts, foreign_key: :author_id
```

After it you can just write `current_user.posts` in the controller

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Post created."
    redirect_to post_path(@post.id)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

And please, read again about [associations in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: The only thing I would say is that the OP doesn’t actually want `save!`, as that will error. `save` (no !) returns a Boolean about whether the save actually worked. `save` should be used here.

Comment: @Nate, good catch, thank you! Missed `!` when copy-pasted from the question

Comment: I figured. No problem!

Comment: Now, it says "unknown attribute for :author_id for Post"

Comment: @arehvb, did you run `rake db:migrate` and restart rails server?

Comment: yes, now it says: User(#47015106648260) expected, got "test" which is an instance of String(#47015080074780)

Comment: Could you please add this last FULL error to the question?

Comment: @arehvb, full error - it is error with full stacktrace for it. Looking to it we can see, which line of code produced the error

Comment: @arehvb now that you’ve made the changes that @Vasilisa suggested, you should be able to just delete the line that it’s erroring on all together. The post should already have a user set because you’re doing `current_user.posts.build`. The error is just telling you that you can’t set author to a string, since it needs to be set to a User object.

Comment: alright, new issue: it works, but is now displaying the author as "<User:348537537537583>" or some other number like that.

Comment: @arehvb, happy that all is working now. If my answer helped you, could you please accept it?